# new array from existed

Tags: php

I have an array

`$t1 = array(2,1,8,18,10);`

I want to create new arrays from this one using defined keys

```
$t11 = array("no" => 2, "to" => 1);
$t12 = array("no" => 1, "to" => 8);
$t13 = array("no" => 8, "to" => 18);
$t14 = array("no" => 18, "to" => 10);
$t15 = array("no" => 10, "to" => 0);
```

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: my problem is - how to put values from existed array to created new ones (in loop as it is mentioned below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CachingIterator` and `extract`

```
$a = array(2,1,8,18,10);
$it = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($a));
$t1 = array();
foreach ( $it as $v ) {
    $var = array("no" => $v,"to" => 0);
    if ($it->hasNext()) {
        $var["to"] = $it->getInnerIterator()->current();
    }
    $t1[] = $var;

}

extract($t1, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "t1");
var_dump($t1_0,$t1_1,$t1_2,$t1_3,$t1_4);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  'no' => int 2
  'to' => int 1
array (size=2)
  'no' => int 1
  'to' => int 8
array (size=2)
  'no' => int 8
  'to' => int 18
array (size=2)
  'no' => int 18
  'to' => int 10
array (size=2)
  'no' => int 10
  'to' => int 0
```

Comment: thanks for response and help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop with a counter variable such as $i, use $t1[$i] and $t1[$i+1] to make your new array, increment $i, then repeat.